# CodeIgniter: Issue passing argument to model

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm attempting to pass a model an argument, which is passed in from the controller. So in the URL if I enter the url `www.foobar.com/report/ecomma/ford` ('report' is controller name, 'ecomma' the function 'ford' the argument), I'm expecting the controller to pass the model the argumnet `'ford'` the model should then perform the sql query with the argument passed in to it, `LIKE "%$brand%"";`.

I have the following controller (called report):

```
    public function ecomma($brand){
        $this->load->model('report_model');
        $data ['query'] = $this->report_model->generate_brand_data_report($brand);
        $this->load->view('brand_report_view',$data);
    }
}
```

The model associated with the controller is here:

```
public function generate_brand_data_report($brand = ''){
$sql = "SELECT 
    DISTINCT pd_model_code AS `Model_SKU`,
             pd_model_description AS `Model_Title` 
    FROM iris_product_data
    WHERE pd_vendor LIKE "%$brand%"";

$query = $this->db->query($sql);
return $query->result();

}
```

The argument is not passed in however, can anyone see the issue here?

Comment: Can you check if the url is first redircting to this function first? And also check for the value in that variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't use double quotation inside double quotation you can use single or double like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT 
DISTINCT pd_model_code AS `Model_SKU`,
         pd_model_description AS `Model_Title` 
FROM iris_product_data
WHERE pd_vendor LIKE \"%$brand%\"";
```

or

```
 $sql = "SELECT 
DISTINCT pd_model_code AS `Model_SKU`,
         pd_model_description AS `Model_Title` 
FROM iris_product_data
WHERE pd_vendor LIKE '%$brand%'";
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I didn't spot the mistake and assumed the issue was with how I'd handled something in Code Igniter, this is only my second day day developing with CI!

Answer (score 2):

In Active Record you can write your query as

```
$this->db->distinct('pd_model_code AS Model_SKU');
$this->db->select('pd_model_description AS `Model_Title`');
$this->db->like('pd_vendor',$brand);
$query=$this->db->get('iris_product_data');
```